# ctrl+space key binding not working for commenting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

After installing Sublime Text 3 (Build 3059) I tried to configure some key bindings as I usually did in the past. So I configured this in "Preferences \ Key Bindings - User":

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+space"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } }
]
```

Well, this simply does not work. I can see the key binding is registered when I hover over to "Edit \ Comment \ Toggle Comment" as there is the key binding shown in grey right next to the "Toggle Comment" text. Commenting works when I *click* the Toggle Comment menu item, but not with the key binding.

When binding `shift+space` commenting works as expected. So, why won't `ctrl+space` do?

Comment: try with only one space, not multiple spaces.

Comment: What @Sneftel is saying is that you have `spaces` instead of `space` (which is plural) and that wont work!

Comment: Gna, I'm sorry, kind of a pasting error. I indeed have `ctrl+space` inside my config and it does not work. Updated the question.

Comment: This works just fine for me with Build 3062 on Win 8.1.

Comment: Just to be safe I uninstalled the Package Manager, no change. The key binding still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it had to do with ibus. I could fix it by following these steps:

1. `$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
2. `$ dconf-editor`
3. Go to `desktop \ ibus \ general \ hotkey`
4. Change the value for `triggers` from `['<Control>space']` to `[]`

Answer (score 1):

## It's work only when file `Syntax` is defined.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type name of syntax, like `Java`, `C++`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, `SQL` etc...

### Default (Linux) settings:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+/"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
```

### Line comment:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
[image]

### Block comment:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Syntax is defined, I tried it with Ruby and some other file formats. When using the default key binding, commenting works. It's just that the custom key binding doesn't work.

Comment: @tbuehlmann I just tiered `shift+space` and `ctrl+space`; it's work for me. What OS you use ?

Comment: @tbuehlmann Try to setup **[iBus](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/Ubuntu)**; Check this answers **[[1](http://askubuntu.com/a/464066/181228)]**, **[[2](http://askubuntu.com/a/362149/181228)]**.

Comment: ibus was already installed and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ibus` didn't change anything either.

Comment: @tbuehlmann Last attempt; Check this answers **[1](http://askubuntu.com/a/421021/181228)** & **[2](http://askubuntu.com/a/386469/181228)**.

Comment: First, thank you for your great commitment. Those two didn't help either, but I found the answer somewhere else. It had indeed to do with ibus. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a Sublime Text 3 problem.

Something is grabbing the keyboard shortcut before it reaches the editor.

As you are on ubuntu 14.04 my best guess is ibus.

See the issue on their launchpad: [ibus breaks emacs and eclipse control-space keybinding](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278569)

Maybe the given workaround [run "ibus exit" in .config/lxsession/Lubuntu/](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278569/comments/22) suites you.

cheers,

Martin

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I found an easier way to solve this problem.
First type `html` in sublime, then press `tab`. It will work.
Also, you can Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` in order to see more shortcuts.