# Can't fire up Package Manager with ctrl+shift+p in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, gnome

After installing `gnome-session-flashback` when I hit `ctrl+shift+p`, nothing is happening. How to solve it?

PS I have checked `Keyboard Shortcuts`, but there is nothing about `ctrl+shift+p`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24905104/4200092) suggests that your problem might be caused by ibus.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Install [XFCE](http://xfce.org) instead of using [GNOME Flashback](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeFlashback).</s>

GNOME defines *global* keyboard shortcuts, which [may override per-program ones](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5483081?tstart=0). Try [changing/disabling them](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) so that GNOME no longer attempts to "take over" those key combinations:

> To change a keyboard shortcut:
>
> 1. Select **Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Shortcuts**.
> 2. Select the shortcut that you wish to edit by clicking on it.
> 3. Once the shortcut is selected, click on the shortcut key combination to edit it.
> 4. Press your desired shortcut key combination as you would enter it to use it. The keys that you can use include <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>
>      number and letter keys.
>
> > Mnemonic key combinations, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will not work.
>
> 5. Once you have entered your new shortcut, it will automatically be saved and you should see it in the list next to the corresponding
>      action.

Alternatively, you could try changing the settings using `dconf-editor` as suggested by [this blog post](http://aprilmayjune.org/2012/04/17/change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-shell-gnome-3/):

> I really love Gnome 3 and its Shell, but I almost went nuts on this.
>   It really took me a while to finally figure this out. To make a really
>   short blog post even shorter:
>
> Use `dconf-editor` (from package `dconf-tools`) and go to
>   `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`. There you have it.
>
> Why would I want to change keyboard shortcuts? Some of them (namely
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) clash with [IntelliJ IDEA’s](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) shortcuts.
>   That’s why! :-)

Comment: I have checked `Keyboard Shortcuts`, but there is nothing about `ctrl+shift+p`

Comment: Do you have any other desktop environments (such as KDE/LXDE) installed? If so, do you have the same problem with those, or is this purely a GNOME problem?

Comment: No, no other desktop environments. I had Unity before.

Comment: OK, I've just installed Sublime Text 3 on my Debian/XFCE machine as a test and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` seems to be working correctly, so it looks like this is specifically a GNOME problem.